# Retrieving Data created by Safari Extensions

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, ninjakit

So recently Safari upgraded to Safari 12 and all extension not created through the Extensions API no longer work properly. This is troublesome for me, as I have been working on a project for the past few years that required the use an extension that no longer runs. The extension in question is an extension for creating browser scripts called Ninjakit, and as far I can tell it no longer exists in any form (the website I originally downloaded it from is currently completely defunct), so there is little chance of it being updated to be compatible with Safari 12. As such, I have been looking into workarounds I can use to make it so that I can continue using the extension. The best strategy I have found is the one outlined on this blog post: https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/install-any-safari-extension-macos-mojave/. While following the instructions on that page has allowed to me to successfully make it so I can continue using Ninjakit, all the 200+ scripts I had written with Ninjakit are missing (note that these scripts were created entirely for my personal use and thus were not uploaded to the internet at any point in time). This is unacceptable to me. The blog post does provide instructions for importing an extension's old settings, but when I try and follow those instructions, I run into an impassable roadblock. At one point the instructions say to make modifications to the file ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.Extensions.plist. According to the instructions, there is data that can be modified under "Root", but when I open the file in XCode, "Root" is completely empty.

To be perfectly honest, there are probably other, better extensions I could use for scripting in Safari (or possibly even a different browser such as Chrome), and I would honestly be fine with abandoning Ninjakit if it weren't for the fact that currently, doing so would mean re-writing all my old scripts from scratch, which is simply not feasible. As these scripts are all ultimately just Javascript code, I assume Safari must have been storing them in some physical form on my machine but I cannot for the life of me figure out which file would contain this data. I have searched through the Library and Time Machine with no success. If anyone knows how I can re-access my old scripts, the help would be greatly appreciated -- even just being able to copy-paste the Javascript code into a different extension would satisfactory for me.

If it helps my machine hasn't yet been upgraded to OSX Mojave -- it's still on OSX High Sierra. While I don't know the exact version number (I'm currently posting this from a different machine), I can easily retrieve that information if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You may have already solved this at this point, but for anyone else looking, your ninjakit scripts are stored in this file (not literal asterixes but random characters):

```
~/Library/Safari/LocalStorage/safari-extension_net.os0x.ninjakit-**********_0.localstorage
```

I do not know whether updating to Mojave deletes this file or not, but in that case you would have to retrieve it from a backup.